# Elastic query BOOL with AND & OR

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

I am new with Elastic. I am trying to do a simple query that in sql would be:

```
Select * from [movies] where is_adult = false AND (movie_title like '%xxx%' OR genre = 'xxxx')
```

In Elastic the closer that I could go was:

```
GET /idxsearch/movies/_search
{
  "size": 10,
  "query": {
    "bool": {
       "filter": {
        "term": {
          "is_adult": false
        }
      },
      "must": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "xxx",
            "operator": "and",
            "fields": [ "movie_title.default^5", "movie_title.shingles" ]
          }
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {"term": {
          "genre.name": {
            "value": "xxxx"
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

But testing this query with some data I see that is not working....

cheers

Just to check, here is part of the custom analyser:

```
"shingle_analyzer": {
    "type": "custom",
    "tokenizer": "standard",
    "filter": ["lowercase", "asciifolding", "shingle_filter"]
}

"shingle_filter": {
  "type": "shingle",
  "min_shingle_size": 2,
  "max_shingle_size": 2
}

"match_title":  {
"type": "text",
"fields": {
    "default":  {"type": "text", "analyzer": "default_analyzer" },
    "snowball": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "snowball_analyzer"},
    "shingles": {"type": "text", "analyzer": "shingle_analyzer" },
    "ngrams":   {"type": "text", "analyzer": "edgengram_analyzer", 
                    "search_analyzer": "default_analyzer"}
}
```

Comment: What's the mapping for `movie_title` and `genre` fields?

Comment: @AndreiStefan Text with custom analyser

Comment: This I understood from the sub-field name :-) (`shingles`) but wanted to see exactly what you did with the custom analyzers.

Comment: @AndreiStefan Just updated the question with the analyser. take a look. cheers.

Comment: Would be nice to see how `default_analyzer` looks like as well.

Comment: Also your query DSL doesn't match what you expressed in your SQL, the `multi_match` also needs to go inside the `bool/should`

Comment: @Val how would be? like this:
`code`
Bool
    FILTER
    BOOL
         SHOULD
                  MULTI_MATCH on title
                  MATCH  genre
`code`